# How to format date for group function in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb

The documents in my DB look like this:

```
        "currency": "euro",
        "_id": "605c88f480db631f542d4752",
        "categoryName": "Food",
        "categoryType": "spendings",
        "amount": 45,
        "description": "Mozarella buns",
        "user": "603cf9f94ca6c518747e46bb",
        "madeAt": "2021-03-25T12:58:28.690Z",
        "__v": 0
```

The goal is to generate some graphics based on the amount of the transactions of this kind. In order to do this, for the first one I need to get the sum for all the transactions of a certain categoryType for the last 5 days. I am trying to do this:

```
transRoutes.get('/getGraphData/:type/:daysAgo/:category/:defaultCurrency', async (req, res) => {

    let startDate = moment().add(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    let endDate = moment().subtract(req.params.daysAgo, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    let queryParams = {};

    if (req.params.category !== 'all') {
        queryParams = { categoryType: req.params.type, madeAt: { $gte: endDate, $lte: startDate }, categoryName: req.params.category };
    } else {
        queryParams = { categoryType: req.params.type, madeAt: { $gte: endDate, $lte: startDate } };
    }

    Transaction.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $match: queryParams
            },
            {
                $group: { 
                    _id: { $dateToString: { date: "$madeAt", format: "%Y-%m-%d" }, category: "$categoryType" } ,
                    amountSum : {$sum:'$amount'}
                    
                }
            },
        ],
        (err, result) =>{
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
              } else {
                res.json(result);
              }
        }
    );
```

But the problem is that the dates being ISODates, the group function doesn't group dates from the same day because they have different times of creation. I tried formatting like in the code above but i get a mongoError.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks,
Adelina

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: If i try to GET to http://localhost:5000/api/trans/getGraphData/spendings/5/all/euro, i get this: 
    "operationTime": "6953266638762278920",
    "ok": 0,
    "code": 15983,
    "codeName": "Location15983",
    "$clusterTime": {
        "clusterTime": "6953266638762278920",
        "signature": {
            "hash": "hp7xYsoOD6yfeTxKxzFmIyzmHJY=",
            "keyId": "6927232780396920836"
        }
    },
    "name": "MongoError"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

considering your data is:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("5db07579f359d4a09a518ca6"),
  modifyDate: 2021-04-19T15:00:00.000Z,
  categoryName: 'Food',
  amount: 5 }
{ _id: ObjectId("5db07579f359d4a09a518ca7"),
  modifyDate: 2021-04-20T15:03:59.617Z,
  categoryName: 'Food',
  amount: 2 }
{ _id: ObjectId("5db07579f359d4a09a518ca8"),
  modifyDate: 2021-04-20T15:03:59.617Z,
  categoryName: 'Food',
  amount: 1 }
```

you can do projection at the first level aggregation to shape your desired data, then use $group to do the summation based on the combined key

so your query will be:

```
db.prod2.aggregate([
  { $project: { amount: 1, categoryName: 1, dayOfModifyDate: { $dateToString: { date: '$modifyDate', format: '%Y-%m-%d' } } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { dayOfModifyDate: '$dayOfModifyDate', categoryName: '$categoryName' },
      amountSum: { $sum: '$amount' },

    },
  },
]);
```

which will result

```
{ _id: { dayOfModifyDate: '2021-04-20', categoryName: 'Food' },
  amountSum: 3 }
{ _id: { dayOfModifyDate: '2021-04-19', categoryName: 'Food' },
  amountSum: 5 }
```

Comment: This works at some level, but the only problem is that it doesn't filter the transactions which are used to add to the sum according to the parameter I'm sending in the route. It makes sums of all categoryTypes and if i try to user categoryType: req.params.type it gets mixed up and simply adds all the sums from a day

Comment: I fixed this in the end by adding another object with {$match: queryParams} right inbetween $project and $group ones. Thank a lot for your answer :)

Comment: of course you have to do $match before doing $projection and $group, exactly like what you have done in your code